# Having trouble with memory leak

Tags: c, valgrind

I am trying to generate a Fibonacci sequence by allocating space for 2 elements, so I need my array `a[0]` and `a[1]` to be constantly updated until it outputs 89 as the final number.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fib2(int* a);

int main()
{
  int *pointer;

  //allocates space for 2 elements for pointer
  pointer = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int*));

  //prints first two fibonacci values
  printf("0 1 ");

  //calls fib2 func and apsses pointer into it
  fib2(pointer);

  //frees pointer memory
  free(pointer);

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}

//generates fibonacci sequence
void fib2(int* a)
{
  int i;

  //allocates space for 2 elements
  a = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int*));
  //initial fibonacci array initialized
  a[0] = 0;
  a[1] = 1;

  //generates and calculates fibonacci sequence and prints
  for(i = 2; i < 12; i++)
  {
    a[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];
    printf("%d ", a[i]);

  }

}
```

I tried freeing of `a[]` by doing `free(a);` but it outputs to the console like this

[image]

**edit this is the valgrind output
[image]

Comment: `a = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int*));` in `fib2` immediately throws away whatever `a` was pointing to previously. Worse, you index slots that were never allocated.  And after all that, the original pointer from `main` is no longer valid, yet `free` d anyway. In short, this is completely broken. Frankly, you don't need an array for your task in the first place if the intended goal is just to spew Fibonacci numbers. A simple loop and two variables can do that.

Comment: Also you are trying to access out of bound.

Comment: Why are you allocating pointers to int but storing ints in the array? Why have you only allocated 2 elements but then proceed to try (and fail to) access 12 of them?

Comment: Is the point of the exercise to learn memory allocation? Because this program does not need it at all.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Yea I need to learn how to malloc

Comment: @truong A big part of learning "how to X" is learning "when to X". *Using* `malloc` is straightforward once you get clear that memory is just a sequence of individual bytes with (mostly) sequential addresses. What you need to learn is how to recognise a problem whose solution would benefit from dynamic memory allocation. Forcing `malloc` inappropriately into a solution doesn't provide much learning IMHO. The key feature of a problem which does require `malloc` is that you don't know when you are writing the program how much memory you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems.

**Problem 1** Wrong `malloc`

```
int *pointer;

//allocates space for 2 elements for pointer
pointer = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int*));
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `sizeof` should be `sizeof(int)` as you want to allocate space for a number (2) int. Besides that you don't need the cast. A better way to write this is:

```
pointer = malloc(2 * sizeof *pointer);
```

**Problem 2** You never use `pointer` for any thing

You do pass its value to `fib2` so that its value goes into variable `a`. However, immediately after you do:

```
a = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int*));  // also sizeof wrong again
```

so you actually overwrite whatever value that passed. Your call of `fib2` could just as well be:

```
fib2(NULL);
```

In other words: Don't do `malloc` both in `main` and in `fib2`. Select one place.

**Problem 3** The memory in malloc'ed in `fib2` are never free'ed

Your current code leaks memory because `fib2` doesn't end with code like: `free(a);`

**Problem 4** You allocate too little memory

Obviously you want 12 elements in the integer array but you only allocate ! Change code to be:

```
a = malloc(12 * sizeof *a);
```

Putting things together it could look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fib2(int* a, int n);

#define NUMBERS_TO_CALCULATE 12

int main()
{
  int *pointer;

  //allocates space for NUMBERS_TO_CALCULATE elements for pointer
  pointer = malloc(NUMBERS_TO_CALCULATE * sizeof *pointer);
  if (pointer == NULL) exit(1);

  //calls fib2 func and apsses pointer into it
  fib2(pointer, NUMBERS_TO_CALCULATE);

  // ... use pointer for other things ...

  //frees pointer memory
  free(pointer);

  return 0;
}

//generates fibonacci sequence
void fib2(int* a, int n)
{
  int i;

  if (n < 2) return;

  //initial fibonacci array initialized
  a[0] = 0;
  a[1] = 1;

  //prints first two fibonacci values
  printf("0 1 ");


  //generates and calculates fibonacci sequence and prints
  for(i = 2; i < n; i++)
  {
    a[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");    
}
```

Note: If you don't want to use `pointer` for other things in `main`, I'll suggest that you move the `malloc` and `free` into `fib2`

**Edit based on comments from OP**

In comments OP tells about a number of restriction like:

1. Must use `malloc`
2. Only allowed to `malloc` 2 integers (I assume this also means that local variables are not allowed in `fib2`)
3. Function prototype must be `void fib2(int* a)`
4. Must print values less or equal 89

With those restrictions the program could look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fib2(int* a);

int main()
{
  int *pointer;

  //allocates space for 2 integer elements for pointer
  pointer = malloc(2 * sizeof *pointer);
  if (pointer == NULL) exit(1);

  //initialize fibonacci start values
  pointer[0] = 0;
  pointer[1] = 1;

  //calls fib2 func and apsses pointer into it
  fib2(pointer);

  //frees pointer memory
  free(pointer);

  return 0;
}

//generates fibonacci sequence
void fib2(int* a)
{
  //prints first two fibonacci values
  printf("%d %d ", a[0], a[1]);


  //generates and calculates fibonacci sequence and prints
  while(a[1] < 89)
  {
    a[1] = a[1] + a[0];   // Calculate next number and save in a[1]
    printf("%d ", a[1]);  // Print it
    a[0] = a[1] - a[0];   // Calculate the number for a[0]
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: My assignment says that I can only allocate memory for 2 elements, however, so wouldn't I need my malloc to be 2 * sizeof pointer or int?

Comment: @Truong ahh - you should have told!! That means that you shall not save **all** the generated numbers. Just save the two that you need for calculating the next number. In other words - the `for` need to be changed.

Comment: Also I was provided a skeleton code so I cannot change the fact that 
void fib2(int* a)
only lets (int* a) in

Comment: @Truong See updated answer that handles the "extra" restrictions you mention in comments.